# vbscript para traer info del usuario

Tags: vbscript, vbs

Tengo un vbscript generado que ya funciona que me trae la ip y el hostname de la pc en donde se ejecuta, pero ahora necesito agregarle también que me traiga el usuario con el que está logeado.

```vb
dim NIC1, Nic, StrIP, CompName

Set NIC1 =     GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

For Each Nic in NIC1

    if Nic.IPEnabled then
        StrIP = Nic.IPAddress(0)

        Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        CompName= WshNetwork.Computername

        MsgBox "IP:  "&StrIP & vbNewLine _
            & "Nombre del Equipo:  "&CompName,4160,"asdasd"

        wscript.quit

    End if
Next
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema es?

Answer (score 0):

Con la instrucción

```
strUsuario = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
```